# Ajax form get error on Nodejs Controller calling Jquery getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, controller, sails.js

I got a Node.js / Sails.js app with a client form that submit to a Controller via Jquery ajax:

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form.serialize(),

            success: function(json){
                alert( "Data Returned: " + JSON.stringify(json));
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert( "error" );
            }

        });

    });
});
```

My controller `ArticleController.js` try to get info from Flickr API :

```
**
* ArticleController.js
*
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {
    search: function (req, res) {

        var searchImg = req.param("search");

        var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
            tags: "mount rainier",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            return res.send(data);
        });
    }
};
```

But I got this error :

```
POST http://localhost:1337/Article/search 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
send jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.10.2.js:8136
(anonymous function) main.js:7
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
elemData.handle
```

Of course I tested my controller without getJSON call and it works fine, returning simple string or JSON values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use jQuery inside nodejs : it's a browser (client-side) library !

The simplest replacement to your jQuery call would be to use the super simple and super powerfull `request` module :
https://github.com/mikeal/request

But, if you *really want* to use jQuery inside nodejs, there is also a few solutions out there..
These really aren't the recommanded solutions to make a simple API call. 
But they can be used to do some scraping : parse an HTML page with all the power of jQuery.

In that eventuality, you can give a try to my [`buck`](https://github.com/zipang/buck) module, and give me some feedback..

```
var $ = require('buck');
```

Comment: Of course now it seems obvious to me, I was not awake :D I will try both solutions, request looks great but I am also very interested by buck. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You used JQuery ($.getJson) in your Sails-App - that isn't possible the way you want to.

JQuery uses the Browser-API to make a request, in NodeJs you don't have a browser-API and you don't have JQuery in Sails.

Replace your jQuery-Code with a HTTP-Request in NodeJS. There is a really good example in the node documentation for that:
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/http.html#http.request

Or you could use a library like request (https://github.com/mikeal/request)